# NuGet CLI list does not show any packages but add & delete work just fine

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I have this annoying problem where when I try to list NuGet packages they don't appear. The command I use is:

```cs
nuget list packageid:%NUPKG% -Source "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages"
```

where `%NUPKG%` is the name of the package which contains an appropriate Package ID per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/finding-and-choosing-packages#search-syntax).

However, the packages do show up in Visual Studio 2022 when I use the NuGet Package manager after having added them using `nuget add`. I can also delete those packages with `nuget delete`. So, my question is... why the hell those packages do not show up? Interestingly enough, the same thing happens for pushed NuGet packages in a private repo.

Any ideas anyone?